# how to use PRROC package to get the auc of ROC & PR for random forest in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest, roc, auc

My data resource:https://www.kaggle.com/mlg-ulb/creditcardfraud
The dataset is highly unbalanced, the positive class (frauds) account for 0.172% of all transactions,[image][image]

I was using the PRROC package to get AUC of ROC curve, here is my random forest code:

```
rf.model <- randomForest(Class ~ ., data = training, ntree = 2000, nodesize = 20)
rf_pred <- predict(rf.model, test,type="prob"
```

so, as expected, rf_pred should return the probability of each class :
[image]
Then, i used the following code:

```
fg_rf <- rf_pred[test$Class==1]
bg_rf <- rf_pred[test$Class==0]
roc_rf <- roc.curve(scores.class0 = fg_rf,scores.class1 = bg_rf,curve = T)
```

However, the ROC CURVE turned out to be not what as i expected
[image]
The same problem occurred for PR curve. Is it because of high imbalance in class?
And assuming rf_pred returns the probability of 0/1, how can i let fg_rf equals to the probability of calss=1, is my code:`fg_rf <- rf_pred[test$Class==1]` correct?

Comment: We could check it out if you made a reproducible example :-)  What is the data? 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Hi, my data has high imbalance in class,     0:199021  ;   1:345. Should i balance the class in training data before use this training data to train model right?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your `head(rf_pred)` results, it is obvious that your `predict` function returns (hard) classes (i.e. 0/1), and not probability scores, probably due to your `type="pro"` typo (it should be `type="prob"`).

The `scores.class0` & `scores.class1` arguments of the `roc.curve` method should be probability scores, and not hard class predictions.

Correct the typo in `predict` and you should be fine, but most probably you need to also switch the scores - as they are now you are assigning your class 1 points to `scores.class0`:

```
rf_pred <- predict(rf.model, test,type="prob")
fg_rf <- rf_pred[test$Class==1]
bg_rf <- rf_pred[test$Class==0]
roc_rf <- roc.curve(scores.class0 = bg_rf, scores.class1 = fg_rf, curve = T)
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out, but actually i used type="prob" still have the same result, could you please help me check it out?

Comment: @kylechan Your `rf_pred` certainly does not seem to contain probability scores; and did you switch `scores.class0` & `scores.class1` as I show in my snippet? Do you actually use the example from the package vignette?

Comment: Also i tried switch bg_rf and fg_rf, still AUC is 0.5

Comment: I have a theory: my data has high class imbalance,     0 :199021 :    1:345 
, so actually i used SMOTE function to re-balance the class in training data, and i should use this balanced class training data to train the random forest instead of the original imbalanced one,right?

Comment: Hi, just updated my question, maybe it can help you better understand it

Comment: @kylechan Class imbalance changes everything (you should have included this info in the question). Given that, your AUC is not strange - and yes, you should use the SMOTE-balanced dataset to train your classifier